# Can two different applications be made using the same React codebase?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, redux, react-router, react-router-redux

I have made a server side rendering application using React, Redux, Node.js and webpack. Now I would like to make another application with a few extra components which will also reside in the same code base. My requirements are:

- I should be able to run both applications without each affecting the performance of the other.
- The few components which I have added in the new application should not be accessible in the old application.

Comment: Would both of these applications use the same server?

Comment: @LeopoldJoy No,They use different servers

Comment: Ok, how are the two connected then? Are you just duplicating the codebase?

Comment: @LeopoldJoy No,It's the same code base.Ideally we need to trigger the builds differently for two applications

Comment: So can't you just server different pages depending on the request and each page can contain the appropriate components?

Comment: @LeopoldJoy They are different application and i don't want users of one application get access to another, in fact it should be restricted

Comment: Ok, so why don't you just control which content (components) you serve to each user using something like `Express.js` on the backend? That way you can restrict the content you serve each user.

Comment: @LeopoldJoy Can you give a brief outlay of the thing you are talking about

Comment: Do you use something like [`react-router-redux`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/tree/master/packages/react-router-redux) to manage your routes? You could serve different routes for different URLs and even restrict access to certain routes (require authentication), [like this](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-redux/examples/AuthExample.js#L118). Each route can contain different combinations of components.